# MuliDex class cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-multidex

Good day to all the geniuses out there. I need help solving my apps 64k limit. I did everything according to the book.I added these lines in my app build.gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ihive.quintesentialtechs.activity"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true;
}
```

and then added a multidex aar module dependency

```
compile project(':multidex-1.0.1')
```

I then went on to override the attachBaseContext method like so

```
 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

by the way my App class extends Application not MultiDexApplication and in my manifest i did this

```
<application
    android:name="com.ihive.quintesentialtechs.application.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

So the problem is that in my app class the  MultiDex class cannot be resolved, I tried to invalidate and restart the caches nothing works! please please someone help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: You include same library multiple times in your project, remove one of them.

Comment: Did you tried with dependency `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after adding the dependency, the error still persist, try restarting android studio, if same error, delete the .gradle folder of the project and build again. let the app download all dependencies from scratch again. hope this help.

Comment: I deleted the .gradle folder as you said and it worked like magic...thanx man

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` to the **build.gradle** file, in the dependencies section.

Comment: it didn't work...but Aliyu Abdullahi's solution worked!

Comment: classic android :| @johncurtis32